# How do I add a dynamic Facebook like button to every node of a certain content type

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript, social-network

One very comfortable solution to that problem is provided by http://drupal.org/project/fblikebutton. Unfortunately the positioning of the button isn't flexible enough for my needs.

I want every single node of one certain content type to have a FB like button at its bottom, making the base+node-url like-able. Facebook provides some snippets for that. Since I know that loading many iframes makes the site load very slow, I'ld like to add the JavaScript snippet into the appropriate template file.

[image: Facebook like button JavaScript HTML5 snippet]

My questions now are, in what template file exactly would I inject the little snippets and how do I have to customise the url in the plugin to make it fetch the url of every single node dynamically?

Comment: Facebook Like Button Module will automatically pick the url for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside a [`template_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) I have done:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_node().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $variables['full_url'] = url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE));
}
```

Then in my node.tpl.php, I have

```
<?php // http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ?>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php print $full_url; ?>" data-send="true"
  data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<script>
  (function ($) {
    try {
      FB.XFBML.parse();
    } catch (e) {
      $('.fb-like').remove();            
    }
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

In my html.tpl.php, I will hardcode the JS include so that it is right after the body (so I am not at the mercy of render trees, preprocess, etc:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This is from a pretty specific use case on a recent site.  I am not 100% sure if I tested this with multiple nodes on a single page, as the site I did this on doesn't have pages like that.

Comment: I even did it without the preprocess function. I just 1. wrote the JavaScript SDK into the **html.tpl.php**
2. created a **"node--nameofmycontenttype.tpl.php"** to bring the button only to nodes of that content type and inside that file I wrote the button code and made the url dynamic like that:
`<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php print url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE)) ?>" data-send="false" data-width="340" data-show-faces="false"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You could try: https://github.com/grizzly/jquery.facebook

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.likebutton').facebook("likebutton", {
        url : "http://jquery.com",
        action : "like"
    });
});
```

Which adde a like button to every div, marked with class .likebutton

Answer (score -1):

Try [Facebook Like Button](http://drupal.org/project/fblikebutton) Module

> Rather than having to manually copy/paste the Like this on Facebook
>   code for each piece of content you (or your users) create, this module
>   will automatically add that code to the end of each chosen node type.
>   You are able to add a Like button which likes a given URL (static,
>   e.g. your homepage) or/and put a dynamic Like button on your page to
>   like the page you are actually visiting.

Also there is [Facebook Share](http://drupal.org/project/facebookshare)

> The Facebook Share module enables Drupal site administrators to add a
>   Facebook Share button to selected content type nodes in their
>   website(s).